# Phonegap mobile banking app security

Tags: cordova

We are planing to develop a mobile banking app using Phonegap. Is there any security issue because we are using Phonegap instead of native SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference is that a user who can root their device might be able to get to your source code but that's not much difference than typical web development which has millions of secure implementations. Cordova/Phonegap is a mature framework and to my knowledge there hasn't been any major security breaches reported.

As your developing keep these things in mind:

- Make your mobile app a simple client interacting with a API on the server side.
- Use SSL where you can
- Avoid exposing any server or user credentials
- Obfuscate your source code (below an article on how to do this)

http://www.justbeck.com/three-ways-to-encrypt-phonegap-and-cordova-mobile-applications/